# Ctrl+F function in Qt Application and RedHat Linux is disabled

Tags: qt, keyboard-shortcuts

When I open <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> is disabled.

But cancel Caps Lock and the function is good.

Why? **how to fix it?**

Comment: findAct->setShortcut(tr("Ctrl+F"));

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: I think this is very distro specific. Hence, I'm marking this also as off-topic, but you might have a better luck on http://unix.stackexchange.com.